# How to use to_char in solidDB

Tags: sql, oracle

Any ideas how to use to_char in solidDB when I want to change number of month to the name? 04 - april ? This query works fine on Oracle:

```
select to_char(AddDate, 'mon'), count(*) from firma group by to_char(AddDate, 'mon');
< mar, 77250 >
< nov, 71802 >
< oct, 77520 >
< jan, 77391 >
< jul, 77361 >
< apr, 74872 >
< jun, 74885 >
< feb, 70482 >
< aug, 77397 >
< sep, 74870 >
< dec, 68732 >
< may, 77418 >
```

The same query run against solidDB generates:

```
MONTH               COUNT(*)
-----               --------
mon                   900000
```

So it gives me the results of all rows in the table, without splitting it on different month's names. How to achive in solidDB the same result as in Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Oracle syntax against an Oracle database.

Use [SolidDB syntax](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/soliddb/v6r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.soliddb.sql.doc/doc/solid.sql.syntax.html) against a SolidDB database.

Comment: I used `MONTHNAME` function and it gives me what I want - the name of the month. :)